# How can validation accuracy be more than test accuracy?

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, cross-validation, dense-layers, test-datasets

I have been trying to implement DenseNet on small dataset using k-fold cross validation. Training accuracy is 94% ,validation accuracy is 73% whereas test accuracy is 90%.I have taken 10% of my total dataset as test set. I know some overfitting is present, but how can  validation accuracy be greater than test accuracy?

Comment: Can edit your post to include the total number of samples, the number of samples in your training and test sets, the value of k in k-fold, and finally the standard deviations of your training and validation accuracy?

Comment: Also, your title and question imply `val > test` but your numbers indicates `val < test`.  Please verify that your numbers are correct and clarify your question.